# Slow running cumulative total SQL Server update query

Tags: sql-server

I am running a cumulative total on a table with 133K records for six products and it is taking over an hour each. I have a primary index on ID and index on Product. What can I do to speed this up?

```
Update T_Decile
SET Cum_Pct  = (SELECT SUM(h.Pct)
                FROM   T_Decile h
                WHERE  h.ID <= t.ID
                And h.Product = 'ULTRESA'
               )
From T_Decile t
;
```

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using? Can you share the table definition and some sample data?

Comment: Also share the execution plan, probably you need a single index that covers both `ID` and `product` and INCLUDES `Pct`.

Comment: dbo.T_Decile
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,NPI_CODE varchar(10) null
,LName varchar(35) null
,Specialty varchar(100) null
,Product varchar(100) null
,TRX Numeric(10,5) null
Cum_Pct Numeric(16,15) null
Bucket Numeric(1,0) null

Comment: ID Lname ID LName Specialty Product QTY Tot_Qty Pct Cum_Pct
1 1 Y I C 41  19,994  0.20515% 0.20515%
2 2 M G C 36  19,994  0.18092% 0.38607%
3 3 B I C 33  19,994  0.16485% 0.55092%
4 4 J I C 32  19,994  0.15899% 0.70991%
5 5 L I C 31  19,994  0.15620% 0.86611%
6 6 P G C 31  19,994  0.15495% 1.02106%
I am trying to calculate the last column. I included what I expect to get as an example. I insert the data ordered by Product Asc and QTY Desc so the Cum_Pct is rolled up correctly. I am not sure of the sql version. I know we are running on an Azure server. I am using SSMS 17.8.1

Comment: Are you sure about the restriction to the product 'ULTRESA' in the subquery but not in the main query?

Comment: Wolfgang, That is the way it was in a query I googled.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is sometimes called a triangular query, because of the inequality.  They are always O(N^2).  Great article here: [Hidden RBAR: Triangular Joins](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on a better way to write this update not using a Triangular Join?

Comment: Basically, you need to get rid of the inequality in the join, one way or another.